# How to make camera rotate through a virtual joystick ? I am trying to use the mobile single stick control

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, joystick

i am trying to create a game with two virtual joysticks.The first to control the player movement and the other to control the camera attached to the player.I want it to be a joystick movement mapped to the camara's rotation.How do I go about it ? The player movement works fine.

Comment: what you tried so far

Comment: i tried attaching the mouse look script and activating it through the press of a UI button.But i want it to be a joystick movement.Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on if you intend to script it yourself. If so, you can use the input of the virtual joystick to rotate the transform of the camera.

```
Camera.main.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(virtualjoystick.x ... ));
```

And in third person you could make some snazzy function to orbit the camera around the player. You can google for that. I found these guys doing that in two lines.
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rotate-the-camera-around-the-object.47353/

If you're not scripting yourself, you're going to have to find an asset package online.

Comment: great :) the transform thing worked for me.Thanks :)